# Multiple regression to maximize Kendall's tau

Tags: regression, nonparametric, kendall-tau

I've seen methods for maximizing Kendall's tau using regression with a single independent variable, e.g. [Sen's 1968 article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2285891?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).  I'm interested in fitting coefficients in a multiple linear regression that maximizes Kendall's tau (i.e. the case with multiple independent variables).  Is this possible?

A related question is whether a multivariate Theil-Sen regression maximizes Kendall's tau?

(I know that Theil-Sen is based on Kendall's tau, but I'm not sure it is guaranteed to maximize it.  If so, that would be the answer to the question.  If not, I suspect there is not an elegant approach, and one would need to use brute force calculations.)

Comment: Could you give references to the univariate cases you cite?  How would Kendall's tau be defined for multiple predictors anyway?  Can you give a little more context about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: A description of how this can be done in the univariate case is found in "Estimates of the Regression Coefficient Based on Kendall's Tau" (Pranab Kumar Sen, 1968 -- https://www.jstor.org/stable/2285891?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Comment: And to the second question on defining Kendall's tau/more context, the goal is to maximize Kendall's tau between the fitted regression (let's call it Y where Y is the linear combination of a set of independent variables Xi, i.e. Y=b0+b1*X1+..+bp*Xp) and another variable, call it Z.  The idea would be using Y (the linear combination of X-variables) as a predictor for Z.

Comment: Please put the link and any additional relevant information in your question (via an edit). Note that we have many questions on site relating to [Theil-Sen](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=theil+sen) regression